# Scheme macro - Expand a list into a set of function calls

Tags: macros, scheme

This procedure to identify that a tic-tac-toe row is marked does not work (X _ _ row is identified as fully marked when it is not)

```lisp
(define (won? b m)
  (define (row-marked? r)
    (every?-ec (:vector c (index i) b) (if (memv i r)) [char=? c m]))
  "Returns #t if the mark m won"
  (let ([rr '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))])
    `(or ,@(map (lambda (r) `(row-marked? (list ,@r))) rr))))
```

while the procedure below works

```lisp
(define (won? b m)
  (define (row-marked? r)
    (every?-ec (:vector c (index i) b) (if (memv i r)) [char=? c m]))
  "Returns #t if the mark m won"
  (or (row-marked? '(0 1 2)) (row-marked? '(3 4 5)) (row-marked? '(6 7 8))
      (row-marked? '(0 3 6)) (row-marked? '(1 4 7)) (row-marked? '(2 5 8))
      (row-marked? '(0 4 8)) (row-marked? '(2 4 6))))
```

I've tried with no luck

```lisp
(let ([rr '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))])
    `(or ,@(map (lambda (r) `(row-marked? ,r)) rr)))
```

and

```lisp
(let ([rr '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))])
    `(or ,@(map (lambda (r) `(row-marked? ',r)) rr)))
```

as well. What I'm doing wrong?

My goal is to avoid code repetition and automatically generate the executable `(or ...)` expression while keeping the short-circuiting of both `or` and `every-ec`

Thank you!

Comment: What scheme are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gauche

Comment: That's not a macro, it's a procedure that produces the list `'(or (row-marked ...`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the list executable without using `eval`? My goal is to avoid code repetition and automatically generate the executable `(or ...)` expression while keeping the short-circuiting of both `or` and `every-ec`

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need isn't a macro (and as you've specified it it can not be done by a macro), it's [SRFI 1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)'s [`any`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#any) function:

```
(define (won? b m)
  (define (row-marked? r)
    (every?-ec (:vector c (index i) b) (if (memv i r)) [char=? c m]))
  "Returns #t if the mark m won"
  (any row-marked?
       '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))))
```

A single-list version of `any`, which is all you need, is very easy to write:

```
(define (any/1 p l)
  (if (null? l)
      #f
      (or (p (first l))
          (any/1 p (rest l)))))
```

A fully-fledged `any` is a bit harder to get right, especially if you want it to be efficient in the simple cases.

---

It's worth while perhaps seeing why what you want to achieve can't be  done with a macro.  If you consider the fragment

```
(let ([rr ...])
  (m row-marked? rr))
```

Then can `m` be a macro whose expansion is `(or (row-marked ...) ...)`?  No, it can't be, because macros transform *source code* and the list which is bound to `rr` is not available until run time: the macro does not have the source code it needs to transform.

Really, the thing you want to avoid here, is that the forms in the body of `row-marked?` should be evaluated only as many times until they return true, and the mechanism for doing that is just wrapping them up in a function and calling it only as many times as needed.

However that mechanism is sometimes a bit syntactically clumsy: if I have something like

```
(any (λ (e1 e2)
       (and (integer? e1) (integer? e2)
            (even? e1) (even? e2))
            (not (= e1 e2)))
     l1 l2)
```

I might rather write this as

```
(finding-first ((e1 l1) (e2 l2))
  (and (integer? e1) (integer? e2)
       (even? e1) (even? e2)
       (not (= e1 e2))))
```

And, of course, you can:

```
(define-syntax finding-first
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ ((v l) ...) form ...)
     (any (λ (v ...) form ...) l ...)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The response solves the problem, so I'll accept it, but the response does not explains how to make the code in the question work. I understand that the procedure in the question returns a list `'(or (row-marked? ...`, but how this list can be make executable with a macro is still a question.

Comment: I;ve added an addendum explaining why a macro can't be used here in any useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and highlighting the fact that there is a big difference between the source code that can be transformed with a macro and the runtime values of variables from the source code that have to be transformed with procedures, not macros! It is really useful and helpful! Thank you man!